# Improving the look of tkinter fonts on a High DPI screen

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, tkinter, hdpi, highdpi

When using tkinter to create a more modern looking application, I looked to MS Word to inspire my design. Then I noticed that only when I'm using the application on a High DPI device that it looks so terrible.

[image: Example Image]

Is there a way to compensate and make it look just as crisp?

NOTE: "Don't use tkinter" is not on the table.

Comment: Are you doing sing the default font? Have you tried using a different font?

Comment: The font used above is Segoe UI and I've tested the effect with Arial and Verdana too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found for this is to create a custom widget using the [WCK](http://effbot.org/zone/wck.htm) (Widget Construction Kit). Text displayed using this is automatically Anti-Aliased.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this at the beginning of your code

```
try:
    from ctypes import windll
    windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
except:
    pass
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).